# How to do PyS60 development on OS X

Tags: python, nokia, s60, pys60

Is it possible to do [PyS60](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pys60) development on Mac OS X? There is an XCode-plugin for Symbian C++ -development, but I don't know whether I can create Python-apps for my Nokia phone with that. I'm talking about a more thorough SDK experience than just editing files with Textmate/Emacs and copying them over to the device.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend you add PuTools to your development environment. It allows you to easily sync files between the phone and the computer, and gives you a remote shell with more functions than the default Bluetooth shell.

The "official" PuTools instructions are written for Windows machines, but the tools definitely does work on the Mac as well. [These instructions](http://www.instructables.com/id/PyS60:-PUTools,-Advanced-Python-console-from-your-/) should help.

(As a new user, I can only post one link. If you're looking for the original PuTools website, it's an easy Google search. Good luck! )

EDIT: A warning if you're using PyS60 v2.x on your Symbian device: Unfortunately PuTools hasn't been updated for PyS60 v2. :(

Comment: +1 for this -- putools works really well! You will have code running in the phone a few seconds (/keypresses) after writing it in your favorite editor.

If you insist on having an SDK you might not want to go into PyS60 development at all. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, with python on phone all you need to do is be able to upload the scripts, and use [MWS](http://mymobilesite.net/) that's the simplest way. [MWS](http://mymobilesite.net/) supports webdav for upload, also one can use obexftp and bluetooth to drop the scripts in the right place.

One can also wrap them in SIS files in theory, but I haven't done that myself yet.

Comment: I quess running Python scripts in an emulator under OS X is not possible?

Comment: Not sure, if S60 emulator is available, one could in theory. I know it's not on Linux ;).

Answer (score 1):

I use the komodo edit 5 editor on the mac and point it to the nokia appfwui classes, then the editor will autcomplete the Nokia Pys60 apis for you.

I also use the steps given below to copy the script onto the device to test it (as the emulator is not runnable on mac os x)

http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?t=116771

Answer (score 0):

S60 emulator runs only under Windows, so Mac owners run it under emulator. Heard that it works great.